# Spilt the String in mule

Tags: split, mule

Actually I have value after query from salesforce:

Type field such as : 123  or 123-456:

I want to split this string "type" and assign into two flow variable like below

1. "set-variable variableName="type1" value="#[payload.split('-')[1]]"   the output should be for this 123
2. "set-variable variableName="type2" value="#[payload.split('-')[2]]"    the output should be for this 456

If the Input is 123-456 means it will works perfectly. other wise its shows error. How do I set the flow varaible only if the payload has value otherwise we need to assign the null in the flow variable.

or in dataweave how do I assign the values. Please assist me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information you have provided, looks like you just need a null check before setting the second variable. Also, the index should start from 0.

```
<set-variable variableName="type1" value="#[payload.split('-')[0]]" />

<set-variable variableName="type2" value="#[payload.split('-').length > 1 ? payload.split('-')[1] : null]" />
```

HTH.